# For every services I'm getting same price (output)

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class CarCareChoice{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] choices=new String[5];
    int j ;
    boolean validItem=false;
    double price=0.0;
    int p;
    String str;
    //When i'm entering services I'm getting 5.o for all services plz help
        String[] services={"Am","Bm","Cm","Dm","Em"};

    double prices[]={1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0};
 //Scanner
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("enter");

      str= input.nextLine();
       for(j = 0; j < choices.length;j++){

     if(Arrays.asList(services).contains(str)){
       validItem=true;
       price=prices[j];
       }
       }
       if (validItem)
        System.out.println("service"+""+price);
       else
       System.out.println("Invalis enter");

    }

    }
```

**output**

```
enter
Am
service5.0
```

**output**

```
enter
Bm
service5.0
```

when I enter Am i supposed to get 1.0 for "Bm 2.0 and etc but I'm getting only 5.0

Comment: `Arrays.asList(services).contains(str)` is likely to return `true` on EVERY iteration, so, in your case, you're getting the last value in the `prices` array.  I'd use `Arrays.asList(services).indexOf(str)` instead

Comment: A  `Map<String,Double>` provides very simple access to the price via the service name string.

Answer (score 0):

You rather improve your code as following:

```
System.out.println("enter"); 
List<String> choiceList = Arrays.asList(services); 
str= input.nextLine(); 
int index = choiceList.indexOf(str);
if ( index!=-1 ) 
{
     price = prices[i];
     validItem = true;

}
if (validItem)
   System.out.println("service"+""+price);
else
   System.out.println("Invalis enter");
```

> You need not do this in for loop. Because when you have converted your array to a list then just find the index. If that is -1 then its definitely not a valid item else return the price at that index of the array. ArrayList is backed by an array internally.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static final int INVALID_INDEX = -1;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] services={"Am","Bm","Cm","Dm","Em"};
        double prices[]={1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0};
        String input = "Em";
        int index = Arrays.asList(services).indexOf(input);
        System.out.println((index!=INVALID_INDEX)? prices[index]+"":"invalid input");
  }
}
```

Use a `Map<String,Double>` instead if possible.